# Python pygame window keeps crashing

Tags: python, crash, pygame

Whenever I run my code the Python Window that shows up does not respond. 
Is there something wrong with my code or do I have to re-install pygame and python? 
I get a black pygame window and then it turns white and says not responding? 
Also I am new to this so please make this as simple as possible. I tried looking everywhere for the answer but could not get it in a way that I could understand. 
Please help me out. Thanks :)

## 1 - Import library

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

## 2 - Initialize the game

```
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```

## 3 - Load Images

```
player = pygame.images.load("resources/images/dude.png")
```

## 4 - keep looping through

```
while 1:
    # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
    screen.fill(0)
    # 6 - draw the screen elements
    screen.blit(player, (100,100))
    # 7 - update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

Comment: try putting print statements in to find out where it crashes, a good start would be to put one before the while loop to see if it is getting there or not before it stops working.

Comment: If `if event.type--pygame.QUIT:` is actually in your code, you do have a problem. You want to use `==` instead of `--`.

Comment: i changed it from -- to == but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Does it give you an error message?

Comment: Run it in terminal. Maybe you see some error message (trackback).

Comment: BTW: should be `pygame.image.load` in place of `pygame.images.load` - `image` without `s`

Comment: Nope still no error showing, just the pygame window saying not responding. No clue on what the problem is still :(

Comment: Your program do not have any problem and runs fine after removing the `--` with `==` and changing `pyagme.images.load` to `pygame.image.load`...And if their is any problem in code and you are not using any `try-except` then the code must throw some exception

Comment: @user3027728 Please include the complete traceback of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Don't import `pygame.locals`. It is actually unnecessary, since you are already importing `pygame`.

Also, as @furas said, it should be:

```
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
```

Not:

```
player = pygame.images.load("resources/images/dude.png")
```

This will clear up some of the problems in your code.

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience,if you run pygame code from IDLE it often does not respond at all.Try saving your project as a .py file and then run it with python.exe.It always works for me.
And as furas said use

```
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
```

instead of

```
player = pygame.images.load("resources/images/dude.png")
```

Comment: Best Answer! You must write pygame code and save it to a .py file. Then it works. It kept freezing using jupyter notebook and also frooze when using python shell. Running the .py file did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Replace that for loop with this

```
 while not done:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       done = True
```